# Slow MySql with left join and Group by

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, optimization, mysql-5.7

Below is the Mysql 5.7 Table query which has a left join with the group by. When I execute it takes too much time.
line_items has around 3.5M data and users have 1000 rows.
Below is an index of my table.
Explain plan shows me that uses proper index still takes lots of time.
Is there any way to optimize it in another way?

Query is:

```
SELECT u.id,u.name,u.last_paid_date, ifnull(li.commission_status,0) as cs,
    sum(li.commission_amount) as sum
from users u 
LEFT JOIN line_items li on u.id = li.creator_id
WHERE u.created_at between '2019-05-21 11:44:15.0' and '2019-11-21 11:44:15.0' 
and u.`type` in (1, 2) 
and u.`status` = 1 
and u.`deleted_at` is null 
and li.`deleted_at`is null
group by u.id,li.commission_status;
```

Index is:

```
ALTER TABLE `line_items`
    ADD INDEX `line_items_idx1_creator_id_deleted_at_commission_status`
        (`creator_id`,`deleted_at`,`commission_status`);
ALTER TABLE `users`
    ADD INDEX `users_idx1_status_deleted_at_created_at`
   (`status`,`deleted_at`,`created_at`,`type`,`id`,name,last_paid_date);
```

Explain plan is:

```
id|select_type|table|partitions|type |possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                |key                                                    |key_len|ref                    |rows|filtered|Extra                                                    |
--|-----------|-----|----------|-----|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------|-------|-----------------------|----|--------|---------------------------------------------------------|
 1|SIMPLE     |u    |          |range|users_id_unique,idx_users_status_shop_type_delete,users_idx1_status_deleted_at_created_at                                                                                                    |users_idx1_status_deleted_at_created_at                |17     |                       | 222|      20|Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort|
 1|SIMPLE     |li   |          |ref  |line_items_creator_id_index,idx_line_items_creator_id_commision_status_deleted,line_items_idx_deleted_at_creator_id_commission_status,line_items_idx1_creator_id_deleted_at_commission_status|line_items_idx1_creator_id_deleted_at_commission_status|150    |sofontsy_app.u.id,const| 224|      20|Using index condition                                    |
```

Show Index From users;

```
            Table|Non_unique|Key_name                               |Seq_in_index|Column_name         |Collation|Cardinality|Sub_part|Packed|Null|Index_type|Comment|Index_comment|
            -----|----------|---------------------------------------|------------|--------------------|---------|-----------|--------|------|----|----------|-------|-------------|
            users|         0|users_id_unique                        |           1|id                  |A        |        587|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         0|users_email_unique                     |           1|email               |A        |        587|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         0|vendor_id                              |           1|vendor_id           |A        |        587|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         0|users_user_name_unique                 |           1|user_name           |A        |        587|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|users_shop_id_foreign                  |           1|shop_id             |A        |          1|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|users_file_image_id_foreign            |           1|file_image_id       |A        |          1|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|users_file_shop_profile_id_foreign     |           1|file_shop_profile_id|A        |          2|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|users_file_shop_hero_id_foreign        |           1|file_shop_hero_id   |A        |          2|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|users_file_seller_pdf_id_foreign       |           1|file_seller_pdf_id  |A        |          1|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|idx_users_status_shop_type_delete      |           1|status              |A        |          3|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|idx_users_status_shop_type_delete      |           2|shop_id             |A        |          3|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|idx_users_status_shop_type_delete      |           3|type                |A        |          4|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|idx_users_status_shop_type_delete      |           4|deleted_at          |A        |          5|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|users_idx1_status_deleted_at_created_at|           1|status              |A        |          3|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|users_idx1_status_deleted_at_created_at|           2|deleted_at          |A        |          4|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|users_idx1_status_deleted_at_created_at|           3|created_at          |A        |        587|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|users_idx1_status_deleted_at_created_at|           4|type                |A        |        587|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|users_idx1_status_deleted_at_created_at|           5|id                  |A        |        587|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|users_idx1_status_deleted_at_created_at|           6|name                |A        |        587|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            users|         1|users_idx1_status_deleted_at_created_at|           7|last_paid_date      |A        |        587|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
```

SHOW INDEX FROM line_items;

```
            Table     |Non_unique|Key_name                                               |Seq_in_index|Column_name      |Collation|Cardinality|Sub_part|Packed|Null|Index_type|Comment|Index_comment|
            ----------|----------|-------------------------------------------------------|------------|-----------------|---------|-----------|--------|------|----|----------|-------|-------------|
            line_items|         0|PRIMARY                                                |           1|id               |A        |    3188860|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         0|line_items_id_unique                                   |           1|id               |A        |    3163268|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         0|sort                                                   |           1|sort             |A        |    3189530|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|line_items_order_id_index                              |           1|order_id         |A        |     347716|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|line_items_creator_id_index                            |           1|creator_id       |A        |      10100|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|idx_line_item_type_product_deltete_download            |           1|type             |A        |        319|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|idx_line_item_type_product_deltete_download            |           2|product_id       |A        |     198067|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|idx_line_item_type_product_deltete_download            |           3|deleted_at       |A        |     111996|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|idx_line_item_type_product_deltete_download            |           4|download_count   |A        |     121220|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|idx_line_items_updated_at_deleted                      |           1|updated_at       |A        |       2111|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|idx_line_items_updated_at_deleted                      |           2|deleted_at       |A        |       2111|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|idx_line_items_type_deleted_at                         |           1|type             |A        |        270|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|idx_line_items_type_deleted_at                         |           2|deleted_at       |A        |        270|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|idx_line_items_product_id_deleted_at                   |           1|product_id       |A        |      49404|        |      |    |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|idx_line_items_product_id_deleted_at                   |           2|deleted_at       |A        |      48168|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|idx_line_items_creator_id_commision_status_deleted     |           1|creator_id       |A        |      13041|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|idx_line_items_creator_id_commision_status_deleted     |           2|commission_status|A        |      16005|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|idx_line_items_creator_id_commision_status_deleted     |           3|deleted_at       |A        |      18969|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|line_items_idx_deleted_at_creator_id_commission_status |           1|deleted_at       |A        |          1|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|line_items_idx_deleted_at_creator_id_commission_status |           2|creator_id       |A        |      13634|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|line_items_idx_deleted_at_creator_id_commission_status |           3|commission_status|A        |      17784|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|line_items_idx1_creator_id_deleted_at_commission_status|           1|creator_id       |A        |      15412|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|line_items_idx1_creator_id_deleted_at_commission_status|           2|deleted_at       |A        |      14227|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
            line_items|         1|line_items_idx1_creator_id_deleted_at_commission_status|           3|commission_status|A        |      17191|        |      |YES |BTREE     |       |             |
```

Comment: Did you turn off `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`?  If so, this may be part of the problem.

Comment: @RickJames, No I didn't turn off ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

Comment: Without the `GROUP BY`, how many rows does the query return?

Comment: Without group there are 2853796 rows return in query.

Comment: A lot of rows; I don't see any way to speed it up.

Comment: @RickJames, Any alternative way?

Comment: It may be practical to build and maintain a Summary table (daily), then query that table.